# Avoiding StaleElementReferenceException when dealing with a dynamic table in Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, exception, staleelementreferenceexception

I am having trouble dealing with a dynamic table.

This is our table:

```html
<table class="table" style="min-width: 870px; max-width: 870px">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 30px">
    <col style="width: 200px">
    <col style="width: 80px">
    <col style="width: 70px">
    <col style="width: 200px">
    <col style="width: 50px">
    <col style="width: 50px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right" colspan="3">Media del grupo</td>
      <td class="text-center media" colspan="1">1</td>
      <td class="text-center noeditable" colspan="1"></td>
      <td class="text-center media" colspan="1"></td>
      <td class="text-center media" colspan="1"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Each `<tr>` contains the following:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="indice">1</td>
  <td id="accion-1-alumno-0" data-tooltip="" class="has-tip titulo" title="">Ap_Alumno_1ESOA_1, Nb_Alumno_1ESOA_1</td>
  <td data-tooltip="" class="has-tip titulo" data-selector="tooltipdtk00g" title="">1ESOA</td>
  <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #ed1c24!important">
    <div id="accion-1-celda-0-0-0" class="elemento comentarios">1</div>
  </td>
  <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #000000!important">
    <div class="elemento comentarios"><span id="accion-1-editar-1-0" class="block left ellipsis span  comentario" title=""></span><span id="accion-1-prismaticos-1-0" class="glyphicons glyph_observaciones observacion right"></span></div>
  </td>
  <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #000000!important">
    <div id="accion-1-celda-2-0-0" class="elemento comentarios"></div>
  </td>
  <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #000000!important">
    <div id="accion-1-celda-3-0-0" class="elemento comentarios"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

We are interested in the elements

```html
<div id="accion-1-celda-0-0-0" class="elemento comentarios">1</div>
```

which are being added to a `IList<IWebElement>`

However, when trying to `SendKeys` to the element, the first time it will work correctly, however the second time will always fail with `StaleElementReferenceException`, this is because the previous element (the first one) has changed and with it the page DOM has also changed.

I am trying to find a way to find the element again if `StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown.

So far, both this methods have failed:

### Method one

```
public virtual void Introducir_NotasAlumnos(string nota)
{
    IList<IWebElement> divNota = tablaNotas
    .Select((element, index) => element.FindElement(By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0")))
    .ToList();

    divNota.ToList().ForEach(element => Introducir_Nota(element, nota));
}
```

### Method two

```
public virtual void Introducir_NotasAlumnos(string nota)
{
    int index = 0;

        foreach (IWebElement element in tablaNotas)
        {
            By locator = By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0");

            Introducir_Nota(element.FindElement(locator), nota);

            index++;
        }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is `tablaNotas`?

Comment: tablaNotas is defined as follows:  
        [FindsBySequence]
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "tabla-virtual")]
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div.row.row-overflow.bodyPlaceHolder")]
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "table.table")]
        [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "tbody")]
        [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "tr")]
        private IList<IWebElement> tablaNotas { get; set; }

Comment: Are you sure `By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0");` selector correct. In html provided there are elements `accion-1-celda-0-0-0`,`accion-1-celda-2-0-0` and `accion-1-celda-3-0-0`, but `accion-1-celda-0-1-0` not exist.

Comment: Take into account that I just pasted one tr, but the structure is replicated in each tr, so for `tr0` `accion-1-celda-0-0-0` exists, for `tr1` `accion-1-celda-0-1-0` exists, and so forth

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if my code works. My code in Java but there almost no difference

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg could you shed some light on why a webelement has no refresh or getBy methods? I started a few months ago and still do not dominate Selenium

Comment: when elements are stale, you must re-load the page (not the element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your locators:

- **table**: `.table tbody > tr`
- **table row by index**: `.table tbody > tr:nth-child(1)`

and you method (java code):

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".table tbody > tr")).size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    WebElement row = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ")"));
    By locator = By.id("accion-1-celda-0-" + i + "-0");
    Introducir_Nota(row.findElement(locator), nota);
}
```

You have certain count of rows and you find row element independently, should not throw `StaleElementReferenceException` exception.

Here shorter version:

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".table tbody > tr")).size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Introducir_Nota(row.findElement(By.cssSelector("#accion-1-celda-0-" + i + "-0")), nota);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sers, I used your solution and is working correctly. I am however disappointed that there is no clear way to "refresh" or get the IWebElement by so the element can be searched again in case something like this happens. Thank you.